# Can I run react-native link in my expo project?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use `react-native-image-crop-picker` package in my expo project but I'm getting this error:

```
* src\screens\my-profile\MyProfile.js:91:32 in onPressImageIcon$
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:23 in doResolve
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:12 in Promise
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
- node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:216:8 in async
* null:null in onPressImageIcon
* src\screens\my-profile\MyProfile.js:109:45 in onPress
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\TouchableOpacity.js:235:45 in touchableHandlePress
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:878:34 in _performSideEffectsForTransition
- ... 21 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Please help me to figure this out. Is it even allowed to link in expo?? I'm on a Windows environment and testing app on Redmi 4A which is running on Android 7.1.2

Thanks.

Comment: I havn't use Expo for a while, but i don't think this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.The most limiting thing about Expo is that you can’t add in your own native modules.
if you want to use anything that requires react-native link, then you need to detach your project and then develop it without ExpoKit

Comment: Yep. I don't know why react-native last couple of most force that expo...:( If you develop with expo basic app size is > 25MB and also other things....